# MySQL query against table with latin1 uses function that returns utf8

Tags: mysql, function

I have a select statement in a stored procedure that queries a table that uses latin1 collation.  In the Where clause, I am referencing a function that returns a varchar(25) charset utf8.

In MySQL, both the function and the stored procedure will run with no errors.

The function declaration is:
    CREATE FUNCTION `GETLASTSERVICEDATE`(histType varchar(255), inCAT INT(11), inMRN VARCHAR(24)) RETURNS varchar(25) CHARSET utf8

The select statement with the function is:

```
select * from table_xyz
where (service_date = (select GETLASTSERVICEDATE('IMMUNIZATIONS', 13, mrn)));
```

When I execute the stored procedure as part of code in Visual Studio, I consistently get this error:

```
Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

Anyone know how to fix this error?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

In short, using `COLLATE` (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html),

so your select statement would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_xyz`
WHERE (service_date COLLATE utf8_general_ci = (select GETLASTSERVICEDATE('IMMUNIZATIONS', 13, mrn)));
```

Comment: I did try that as well but it also generates an error:  COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'

Comment: Ah yeah well of course, my bad. I messed up between character set and collation. You could try CONVERT (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html) But you might want to reconsider using mixed character sets, especially if you aim to compare them, as it could result in unexpected behaviour.